# Properties editor not showing when embedding jbpm web designer

Tags: jbpm

I'm trying to use the Web Process Designer that comes with the business central of jbpm.
I have manage to call it and it shows but it does not show the properties editor.

This is the URL that I'm using:
http://ip:port/business-central/kie-wb.jsp?locale=es_MX&path=default%3A%2F%2Fmaster%40MySpace%2FPricing%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fresources%2Fcom%2Fdisalvro%2Fprocesos%2FPortafolios.bpmn&standalone=#StandaloneEditorPerspective%7C$BPMNDiagramEditor?path_uri=default://master@MySpace/Pricing/src/main/resources/com/disalvro/procesos/Portafolios.bpmn&file_name=Portafolios.bpmn&has_version_support=true

It shows the designer with the correct diagram but I cannot see the properties editor on the right.

Added screenshot as per request:
[image: Editor without properties options]

Comment: Some screenshot could help. Have you tried in another internet browser?

Comment: Hello @zhrist, I just added the screenshot, as you can see, on the right there is no properties editor like you usually have if you enter the portal normally.